# Call update stored procedure in insert stored procedure if record exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a stored procedure in another. The issue is that both use the same variables. How do I get them in the embedded procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInsert @foo int, @bar int, @cat bit
    SET @recId = (SELECT TOP(1) id FROM table WHERE foo = @foo)
    IF (@recId IS NULL)
        BEGIN INSERT INTO table
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            EXEC uspUpdate @foo = @foo, @bar = @bar, @cat = @cat
        End
```

Update proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspUpdate @foo INT, @bar INT, @cat BIT;
```

Comment: Doesn't the procedure work correctly? `@foo = @foo` looks legal to me, they mean different things.

Comment: Aside: Since you don't use `@recId` it would be more efficient to use [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check if _any_ row with `foo = @foo` exists. No need to order them and get the first one. Alternatively. if `foo` is a `unique` column you could use [`try`/`catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) around the `insert` and call the stored procedure only if the `insert` fails. Depending on your data it may be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't required to use the names of the parameters when you call a SP, as long as they are in the right order.  Try this instead:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInsert @foo int, @bar int, @cat bit
SET @recId = (SELECT TOP(1) id FROM table WHERE foo = @foo)
IF (@recId IS NULL)
    BEGIN INSERT INTO table
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXEC uspUpdate @foo, @bar, @cat
    END
```

Comment: Thank you very much!